# Passing Json object from java script to java

Tags: javascript, java, json, ajax, spring-mvc

I am new to springs and ajax 
I am having a json object in my java script which is created dynamically 
I need to send this json object from java script using ajax or normal submit()

If it is a string we have hidden inputs.

as of my knowledge if I am not wrong
**a JSON object we cannot store it in hidden**

And I have to receive using java code. 
This is my script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // click on button submit
    $("#save_btn").on('click', function(){
        alert();
        // send ajax
        $.ajax({
            url: 'project_reg_save', // url where to submit the request
            type : "POST", // type of action POST || GET
            dataType : 'json', // data type
            data : $("#reg_form").serialize(), // post data || get data

            success : function(result) {
                // you can see the result from the console
                // tab of the developer tools
                console.log(result);
            },
            error: function(xhr, resp, text) {
                console.log(xhr, resp, text);
            }
        })
    });
});
```

and this is my java code

```
@Controller
public class Save {
    @RequestMapping("/project_reg_save")

    public ModelAndView mymethod(@RequestParam JSONObject obj)//which is not possible  {

        System.out.println(obj);

        return new ModelAndView("Product_reg", "msg", "product Registration");
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe try passing it as a string, then use Java to serialize it?

Comment: It's not request parameter, it's request body. Try changing annotation to `@RequestBody`, and add `consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE}` in `@RequestMapping`

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to

1. change your dataType : 'json' to dataType : 'text'
2. @RequestParam JSONObject obj to @RequestParam String obj
3. JsonObject JsonObj= new JsonParser().parse(obj).getAsJsonObject();

hence you get json object